# Saving output from splitvectorlayer processing as shapefile with PyQGIS

Tags: shapefile, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, splitting, geopackage

I'm working on a plugin wich works on both QGIS 2 and QGIS 3. This plugin can perform a `qgis:splitvectorlayer` if the end user wants to.

As `.gpkg` is the default format in QGIS 3 and i don't want end user to changer their default settings, I want to be able to save splitvectorlayer output as a shape. I just want gpkg files to be converted to shape file in the same folder (p in my code).

I have to use shape format because my plugins relate to a third application that is only compatible with shape files.

```py
couche = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox_2.currentText()
champ = self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.currentText()
path = self.get_enregistrement()
p = path + "/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') + "_" + couche + "_" + champ 
os.makedirs(p)    

split = processing.run("qgis:splitvectorlayer", {'INPUT':self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox_2.currentText(),'FIELD': self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.currentText(), 'OUTPUT' : p})
split_output = split['OUTPUT']
couches_sep = QgsVectorLayer(split_output, "separation", "ogr")
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(couches_sep, "UTF-8", "ESRI Shapefile")
```

After many attempt, this is the only one that doesn't throw me an error but still i don't have my gpkg files converted to shape.

Comment: try `writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(couches_sep, p, "UTF-8", split_output.crs(), driverName = "ESRI Shapefile")`

Comment: I have this error `writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(couches_sep, p, "UTF-8", split_output.crs(), driverName = "ESRI Shapefile")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'crs'`

Comment: okay try without `split_output.crs()`, e.g. `writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(couches_sep, p, "UTF-8", driverName = "ESRI Shapefile")`

Comment: no more error but no shape ...

Comment: BTW, qgis 3.12.1 display a deprecation warning for QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()

Comment: Have you checked this answer: [Splitting vector layer into shapefiles (not geopackage) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324225/63384)

Comment: @ ahmadhanb : well, i can change the default output for processing but, as my plugin is aimed for people with basic knowledge, i want a code that works that can output shape without end user to modify anything from their basic qgis setup

Comment: OK so it seems that the second argument has to be path+filename`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(couches_sep,p+ filename, 'UTF-8',couches_sep.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')`

Answer (score 1):

So here's the complete code to achieve what I wanted :

```py
couche = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox_2.currentText()
champ = self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.currentText()
path = self.get_enregistrement()
p = path + "/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') + "_" + couche + "_" + champ 
os.makedirs(p)    

#separation de la couche active par le champ defini au debut du script et enregistrement dans le dossier c:/GeoMCE/nom_de_la_couche_d_origine
split = processing.run("qgis:splitvectorlayer", {'INPUT':self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox_2.currentText(),'FIELD': self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.currentText(), 'OUTPUT' : p})

def find_files(directory, pattern, only_root_directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename.lower(), pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename
        if (only_root_directory):
            break
count = 0
for src_file in find_files(p, '*.gpkg', True):
    (head, tail) = os.path.split(src_file)
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(tail)
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(src_file, name, "ogr")
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,p+ "/" + vlayer.name(), 'UTF-8',vlayer.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')
output = count
count = 0
for src_file in find_files(p, '*.shp', True):
    (head, tail) = os.path.split(src_file)
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(tail)
    vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(src_file, name, "ogr")
output = count
```