# QGIS Python: Creating a split seperate Split Vector Layer by Shapefile:SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: qgis, python, geoprocessing

I have been following this solution of my Question to make the Vector Split algorithm output in the shapefiles: [Splitting vector layer into shapefiles (not geopackage) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324220/splitting-vector-layer-into-shapefiles-not-geopackage-using-qgis).

The Thing is I want to create a separate geo process called Vector Layer Split (Shapefiles), because

1 I do not want to accidentaly make an error to the Original Script

2 I want to have separate process to make a distinction between the two, because this process is going to be part of a model and this separate script needs to be shared.

I have been followed the instruction as close as I can to edit the algorithm process, but so far I get an Syntax error. **And yes I tried to fix the specific part but the syntax error goes down, and down so as far as the script is concerned there is one big error somewhere that causes the syntax error not just the entire line.**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 119, in loadAlgorithms
    alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 66, in loadAlgorithm
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "", line 724, in exec_module
  File "", line 860, in get_code
  File "", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\VectorSplit(Shapefiles).py", line 47
    class VectorSplit((QgisAlgorithm):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Python versie: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS versie: 3.10.5-A Coruña A Coruña, 984615fe1e 

Python pad:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/xxxx/Documents
```

Here is the script itself:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
***************************************************************************
    VectorSplit(Shapefiles).py
    ---------------------
    Date                 : September 2014
    Copyright            : (C) 2014 by Alexander Bruy
    Email                : alexander dot bruy at gmail dot com
    Email                : x dot x at gmail dot com
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
*   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
"""

__author__ = 'Alexander Bruy'
__date__ = 'September 2014'
__copyright__ = '(C) 2014, Alexander Bruy'
_modified__by = 'x'
__copyright__  = '(C) 2020, x'

import os

from qgis.core import (QgsApplication,
                       QgsProcessingUtils,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingOutputMultipleLayers,
                       QgsExpression,
                       QgsFeatureRequest,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter)

from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithm import QgisAlgorithm
from processing.tools.system import mkdir

pluginPath = os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0])[0]


class VectorSplit((QgisAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    FIELD = 'FIELD'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    OUTPUT_LAYERS = 'OUTPUT_LAYERS'

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Vector general')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'vectorgeneral'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(self.INPUT,
                                                              self.tr('Input layer')))

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField(self.FIELD,
                                                      self.tr('Unique ID field'), None, self.INPUT))

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination(self.OUTPUT,
                                                                  self.tr('Output directory')))
        self.addOutput(QgsProcessingOutputMultipleLayers(self.OUTPUT_LAYERS, self.tr('Output layers')))

    def icon(self):
        return QgsApplication.getThemeIcon("/algorithms/mAlgorithmSplitLayer.svg")

    def svgIconPath(self):
        return QgsApplication.iconPath("/algorithms/mAlgorithmSplitLayer.svg")

    def name(self):
        return 'splitvectorlayer(shapefiles)'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Split vector layer shapefiles')

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        fieldName = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.FIELD, context)
        directory = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)

        output_format = context.preferredVectorFormat()
        if not output_format in QgsVectorFileWriter.supportedFormatExtensions():
            # fallback to gpkg if preferred format is not available
            output_format = '.shp'

        mkdir(directory)

        fieldIndex = source.fields().lookupField(fieldName)
        uniqueValues = source.uniqueValues(fieldIndex)
        baseName = os.path.join(directory, '{0}'.format(fieldName))

        fields = source.fields()
        crs = source.sourceCrs()
        geomType = source.wkbType()

        total = 100.0 / len(uniqueValues) if uniqueValues else 1
        output_layers = []

        for current, i in enumerate(uniqueValues):
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
            fName = '{0}_{1}.{2}'.format(baseName, str(i).strip(), output_format)
            feedback.pushInfo(self.tr('Creating layer: {}').format(fName))

            sink, dest = QgsProcessingUtils.createFeatureSink(fName, context, fields, geomType, crs)

            filter = '{} = {}'.format(QgsExpression.quotedColumnRef(fieldName), QgsExpression.quotedValue(i))
            req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(filter)

            count = 0
            for f in source.getFeatures(req):
                if feedback.isCanceled():
                    break
                sink.addFeature(f, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
                count += 1
            feedback.pushInfo(self.tr('Added {} features to layer').format(count))
            output_layers.append(fName)
            del sink

            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        return {self.OUTPUT: directory, self.OUTPUT_LAYERS: output_layers}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Edit 1: I added a ")" to close the class parenthesis.

```
class VectorSplit((QgisAlgorithm)):
```

Now I got an new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 224, in runAlgorithm
    exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
  File "<string>", line 44, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Edit 3: New Error.

```
NotImplementedError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.name() is abstract and must be overridden 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 68, in loadAlgorithm
    alg = algfactory.instances.pop().createInstance()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.name() is abstract and must be overridden
```

Comment: An extra opening parenthesis in the class declaration line.

Comment: Extra opening? Oh you mean a ")". Now it gives me a different error.

Comment: I get an new error then:
<code> NotImplementedError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.name() is abstract and must be overridden 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 68, in loadAlgorithm
    alg = algfactory.instances.pop().createInstance()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.name() is abstract and must be overridden </code>